# Updating an ActionLink on my page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC solution with a page composed of a table with items loaded 20 rows at a time through an ajax request. I have a link at the bottom of this table for allowing the user to load 20 next rows (rows loaded at the end of the table keeping existing rows).

[image]

So I have:

Index.cshtml: the main page

```
<table class="zebra-striped">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@UserResource.CompanyName</th>
            <th>@UserResource.City</th>
            <th>@UserResource.Street</th>
            <th width="70"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="ListCompanies">
        @Html.Action("RowsList")
    </tbody>

</table>

@Ajax.ActionLink("Load more", "RowsList", new { page = 2 }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "ListCompanies", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter, OnComplete = "AjaxCompleted" })
```

RowsList.cshtml: the partial view

```
@model IEnumerable<Domain.Models.Company>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr id="@item.CompanyID">
        <td>@item.CompanyName</td>
        <td>@item.City.CityName</td>
        <td>@item.Street</td>

        <td nowrap>                                    
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", ...) 
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", ...)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

**The problem:** the link used for loading the next page has a static href like this:

http://localhost/Admin/Company/RowsList?page=2

Everytime the link is clicked, I need:

- loading 20 next items (that's ok)
- updating this link for the next time load the next page serie

Next loading should be possible thanks to:

http://localhost/Admin/Company/RowsList?page=3

http://localhost/Admin/Company/RowsList?page=4

http://localhost/Admin/Company/RowsList?page=5

...

This link is located in my index.cshtml page which does not updated (because only partial view RowsList is reloaded).

Any idea how can I proceed to have this link updated properly? Maybe I had to refactor my code for an easier 'MVC' solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

make a ViewModel for the view that contains a `PageNumber` and a `Company` Properties and pass the page number with the data

or you can use jQuery if you are use client side scripting and loading data via ajax

Comment: The link 'Load more' is located on the Index page which is not refreshed. Only the partial view named RowsList is refreshed through ajax. So even if I use a ViewModel and store the PageNumber in it, I don't see how I can update my link. Maybe you have an idea? Thanks.

Comment: ok if your using ajax then when you press load more , in the callback , update the page number on the link